# What does "ii" mean in "dpkg --list" command output?

Tags: command-line, dpkg

What is the significance/meaning of `ii` at the beginning of the output of

```
dpkg --list
```

command?

```
dpkg --list | grep firefox
```

for example, returns `ii firefox` together with other information.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first `i` is the desired action, `i` stands for `install`.

The second `i` is the current package status, `i` stands for `installed`.

From `man dpkg-query`:

> The first three columns of the output show the desired action, the package status, and errors, in that order.
>
> Desired action:
>
> ```
>             u = Unknown
>             i = Install
>             h = Hold
>             r = Remove
>             p = Purge
> ```
>
> Package status:
>
> ```
>             n = Not-installed
>             c = Config-files
>             H = Half-installed
>             U = Unpacked
>             F = Half-configured
>             W = Triggers-awaiting
>             t = Triggers-pending
>             i = Installed
> ```
>
> Error flags:
>
> ```
>            <empty> = (none)
>             R = Reinst-required
> ```